# Using jQuery's .one on a group of elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to `preventDefault` the first time a `.headlink`  element is clicked. The issue is it's counting the first click on any element with the class.

For example if I have three links with class `.headlink` a user could click one, and the others would no longer be active. Is it possible to combine my code with jQuery's `.this` function to make the `.one` specific to each individual link with this class?

```
$(".headlink").one("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: The `.one` IS specific to each element ([.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `one()` method means that the event will only fire once for each individual instance of the elements in the selector.

Instead, assuming you want the event to fire once only for *all* the elements of the selector, you would need to manually detach all the event handlers for that event. Try this:

```
$(".headlink").on("click.headlink", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.headlink').off('click.headlink'); // remove the handler on all elements

    // your logic here...
    // $(this).doSomethingCool();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/88kLahcz/)

Note that I namespaced the event so that when it's removed only this specific click handler is affected, not all the `click()` handlers that are bound to the affected elements.